# Настройки сервера на Node.js для Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, node.js

Какие параметры нужно прописать в файле server.js на node для установки wordpress?

Comment: – Но зачем вам так?!

Comment: а как еще можно запустить локальный сервер для вордпресса?

Comment: Локально – [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/ru/) или [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress это PHP приложение, текущая версия которого требует для своей работы [PHP](http://www.php.net/) >= 5.6 (работающего в связке с [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) или [Nginx](http://nginx.net/)) и [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) >= 5.5 (см. https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/).

И да, Wordpress не работает под node.js. Совсем.

**UPD:**

Если вам нужно что-то, что работает на локальной машине и не требует навыков настройки, посмотрите на [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/ru/) или [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/).

Comment: под IIS тоже неплохо работает :)

Comment: @PashaPash, наверное, я не пробовал :) Хотя на официальном сайте в разделе требований указаны только apache и nginx.

Comment: На спор, наверное, [можно поднять](https://entwickler.de/webandphp/integrating-node-js-with-php-125830.html) Wordpress на связке node + php-fpm. Но это только если застрять на необитаемом острове без других дел )

Comment: @Sergiks, ого... а я и не знал что так можно :) Но думаю автор совсем не это имел ввиду.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev кстати, он top 1 в категории [web apps на сайте web platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/wordpress.aspx)